# How to join Streaming data with Large Batch data in Apache Beam dataflow in Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In my current use case I get the steaming data from Kafka. To enrich this data, I need to join it with a batch data in gcs bucket. The batch data is usually of huge size. I can't use batch data  as a sideInput for my use case . Is there a way I can achieve it with CoGroupByKey or any other options available?